# Selenium chromedriver send_keysmesses up message in Ubuntu - works fine in Windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-22.04

I have a Python script with Selenium that includes this code to fill a form:

```
search_word = 'Witty'
my_link = 'https://w1tty.page.link/ZXAy8GSX7XxpnHZC7'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@placeholder='Please write your message here...']").send_keys('Hello,\n\nif you need a link for ' + search_word + ' here it is:\n\n' + my_link + '\n\nGreetings\nRZX')
```

Under **Windows 10 (Python 3.10.8, Chromedriver 108.0.5359.71)**  I get:

> Hello,
>
> if you need a link for Witty here it is:
>
> [w1tty.page.link/ZXA…ZC7](https://www.mydealz.de/visit/privatemessage/11480050/10711483)
>
> Greetings
> RZX

Under **Ubuntu 22.04 (Python 3.10.6, Chromedriver 108.0.5359.94)** running the same code I get:

> ZXAy8GSX7XxpnHZC7
>
> Greetings
> RZXw1tty.page.linkHello,
>
> if you need a link to Witty here it is:
>
> https:

When I run the same message as "print" the format is perfect. I guess it's about Selenium send_keys function.

Comment: Can you provide more code? The page is accessible? it would be useful as well

Comment: I don't think it's about the code. It seems like this is a known bug in Selenium on Ubuntu for quite some time. I've tried some described workarounds like .clear() and .click () the textbox before send_keys, chance the keyboard layout to US. And Ubuntu runs on an Oracle VPS. That seems to be a problem, too for send_keys.

Comment: What if you try `.send_keys(f'Hello,\n\nif you need a link for {search_word} here it is:\n\n{my_link}\n\nGreetings\nRZX')` or `f'''Hello,

if you need a link for {search_word} here it is:

{my_link}

Greetings
RZX''''`? I tried with a text area and it worked fine in ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What keyboards/languages do you have installed?

Comment: German and US. I've already tried switching the layout.

Comment: Sounds similar to a quirk a Ukranian user was having where a certain key would paste his clipboard into the form field... odd quirk, but it was related to having the 2nd keyboard installed.  Can't seem to find that old post... forgot the exact solution there.  I would try removing the german keyboard layout.  You might also trying using Keys.RETURN instead of those \n's.

Comment: another possible workaround would be to set your clipboard and then sendkeys of ctrl-v.